# Odd behavior with ternary operation

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, stringstream

The following code is supposed to remove the last char of a string and append `l` (lowercase L) if `flip` is true or `r` if it's false.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << code.substr(0, code.size() - 1);
ss << flip ? "l" : "r";
std::string _code = ss.str();
```

However, when `flip` is true, it appends `1` and when it's false, it appends `0`. How come?

Comment: Not relative to the problem at hand, but why use `std::stringstream` here?  Just copy the string, then set the last character using `s[s.size()-1] = (flip ? 'l' : 'r');`.  (For that matter, I don't think I've ever used `std::stringsream`, although `std::istringstream` and `std::ostringstream` appear frequently in my code.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Precedence issue.

```
ss << flip ? "l" : "r";
```

means

```
(ss << flip) ? "l" : "r";
```

Use

```
ss << ( flip ? "l" : "r" );
```

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with operator precedence.
`<<` has priority over `?` which means `flip` is appended onto `ss` first.

The following should lead to the expected behaviour:

```
 ss << (flip ? "l" : "r");
```